# Google App-Engine run setup.py install for own Python application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, packaging

I realize this might be a super basic question, but I'm developing a Python application on Google App Engine Standard using some of the basic tutorials.

Many of these tutorials are MVC, and that's great, but the code files aren't organized. To illustrate, consider this demo: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-search-python-java/tree/master/product_search_python. The author includes an `admin_handlers.py`, a `base_handler.py` and a `handlers.py` file in the root. Any more handlers, and this would quickly become unweildly.

The solution I am familiar with is to refactor to a more standard project structure like:

```
my_app
    models
        __init__.py
        models_1.py
        models_2.py
    handlers
        __init__.py
        handlers_1.py
        handlers_2.py
setup.py
```

So that in any file in my app, I can call `from my_app.models import model_1` for instance, and then access models specifically defined in that subpackage.

However, I don't see any documentation around how App Engine standard handles application packaging in deployment (i.e. running `setup.py install` when deploying your application.)

There are SO posts for how app-engine runs `setup.py install` to package external python packages, but not material for how app-engine runs your own, and I don't see any examples in their tutorials that include `setup.py` files.

Is app-packing during deployment something that App-Engine supports? Or is it just so basic that they didn't document? Do I have to adopt a framework like Django if I want to do this, or is it possible to do without?

Comment: Are you trying to run the 'system' on your own computer or deploy it to app engine? If you are trying to run on your own computer, installing app engine should give you the app engine launcher, from which you can run and browse your application.

Comment: Question not clear, do you want to have an setuptools pip package that you can install in your app engine environment?

Comment: Yes, @Ian that's precisely what I want. I'd like the deployed app to have package structure so I can call `from my_project.models import models_1` in any part of the project.

I will edit to clarify.

Comment: If I understand your goal correctly, what you want is something inherently supported by python and google app engine doesn't break this. You just need to have an `__init__.py` file for every directory that should be a module. There is no need for a `setup.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setup.py` file is for libraries, what you're attempting to deploy is an application.

If you want to turn all your handlers/models into a separate library (potentially to reuse in other applications), you'd need to give it a `setup.py` file and host it elsewhere, either on your own package index, or as a git repo, and App Engine will install it during the build step.

Otherwise, you can just include these files as part of your application, with no `setup.py` necessary:

```
.
├── main.py
├── my_library
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── handlers
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── handlers_1.py
│   │   └── handlers_2.py
│   └── models
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── models_1.py
│       └── models_2.py
└── requirements.txt
```

And use them in `main.py` like:

```
from my_library.models import model_1
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also need an `__init__.py` file in the `my_library/` directory?